# apache segmentation fault but no core dumps

Tags: apache-2.4

when I start `/etc/httpd/httpd -k start` it works fine. But when I try with `apachectl start`, I see lots of  [httpd] defunct process that come and go and a bunch of messages in the logs:

```
[core:notice] [pid 15126:tid 139966078363520] AH00052: child pid 15517 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I tried adding `CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache-cores` in the httpd.conf but never got any core dumps. 
I'm using Apache 2.4.6.

Comment: Which OS/Distro ?

Comment: I'm using Centos 7 and PHP 5.4.16 (cli)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you restarted Apache after you added CoreDumpDirectory directive, I guess you may be hitting a problem with SELinux stopping httpd from writing a core file.

Try to change context of the destination dir:

```
chcon -Rv -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /tmp/apache-cores
```

or temporary disabling SELinux by changing policy from enforcing to permissive in /etc/selinux/config (this requires system restart, and I don't recommend you keeping it in permissive mode).